# Return back to specific fragment of Activity-A from another Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

[image]

I open the `Message-Fragment` from `Activity-A` and then open the `Camera-Fragment` from `Message-Fragment`. Now current fragment is `Camera-Fragment` and i have media-slider on it. Now I have two options, one is `ImagePreview-Fragment` that is opened if I click the image item on media-slider. Other is `VideoPreview-Activity` that is opened if click the video item on media-slider. So there is one condition of clicking video-item. If I click the video-item on media-slider and video size is bigger than 10 MB, I open the `VideoTrim-Activity` and when trim is completed i call the `VideoPreview-Activity`.

I'm sending a media from `VideoPreview-Activity` or `ImagePreview-Fragment`. So when I send the media I want to return back to the `Message-Fragment` with data.

How can I return back to `Message-Fragment` from `VideoPreview-Activity` (opened from Camera-Fragment) and `VideoPreview-Activity` (opened from `VideoTrim-Activity`). Also if you can help me about how to return back from `ImagePreview-Fragment` to `Message-Fragment` I would be much appreciated. These are seperated questions. Hope you can help.

I open the fragments with adding to backstack `addToBackStack(fragmentTag)`.

Edited : VideoPreview-Fragment must be VideoPreview-Activity
and VidoTrim-Fragment must be VideoTrim-Activity. these are the activities. like you see on the image.

Comment: Can I just confirm a couple of questions before I write an answer? 1. Do you want to be able to hit back button on trim or preview and return to the camera fragment or always to the message fragment? 2. When you say "return back" do you actually mean navigate back or using back buttons or is it actually a progression in the journey that returns you to that point?

Comment: yes i am able to hit. when i hit the back button i return the cameraActivity. i mean return to that point, like finish the acvity or popback progress. in the mean time i need to pass the data to message fragment.

Comment: One last quick one is the MessageFragment the initial view in the activity or is it added  on top of an existing view?

Comment: it is added on top of an existing view. Activity-A has 4 Tabs (Fragments) View. I open the Message-Fragment from Friends-Tab (Fragment).

Comment: K, going to make a quick edit to my answer then

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand everything correctly I think I have a solution. I will ignore all other aspects of the navigation and just focus on the fact you want to go from `VideoPreviewActivity` to the `MainActivity` and adjust the fragment stack, and that this is being triggered from a done button (or something similar) but NOT the back button.

The simple way would be to use the activity result functions `startActivityForResult` which would allow you to use a `onActivityResult` function in the main activity to pass the information back. However you may potentially navigate to the `VideoPreviewActivity` via the `VideoTrimActivity` so you would have to pass this information back through two activities which would be a bit messy.

So my proposed solution has a few steps.

Instead of calling `finish()` on the `VideoPreviewActivity` fire an intent to create the `MainActivity`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
intent.putExtra()//Add your return data here
startActivity(intent)
```

Instead of starting a new `MainActivity` this will return you to the previous one and finish all the activities sat above it in the task task.

Add this function to the `MainActivity`.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

Then in the `onStart` function you can check your intent to see if there is data in there returned from `VideoPreview` and remove the fragments you no longer need.

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra(YOUR_DATA)) {
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
            getSupportFragmentManager(). popBackStackImmediate("MESSAGE_TAG", 0);
}
```

Where "MESSAGE_TAG" is the tag used in the `ft.addToBackStack("MESSAGE_TAG")` call.

This will clear all of the fragments with an `addToBackStack` in the transaction. The `MessageFragment` will start its lifecycle calls again and you can access the data from

```
getActivity().getIntent()
```

Comment: thanks. it is working good for now :) testing with various cases.
but `getSupportFragmentManager(). popBackStackImmediate("CAMERA_TAG", 0)` is not returning me to MessageFragment. Still i see the CameraFragment.
i try to use this and it works well. if is there anything wrong about my code tell me. i use this
`getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack("CAMERA_TAG",FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);`

Comment: No, you are right thats a problem with my example. You can do "CAMERA_TAG" INCLUSIVE or "MESSAGE_TAG"  0. I Will fix my answer.

Comment: It's probably better to use MESSAGE_TAG 0 as that will still work even if you add different fragments.

Comment: then i will use MESSAGE_TAG 0. thank you again for your effort. if you mark my question as useful i would be appreciated.

Comment: @Gapp I have not understood the way which you have implemented above to return back to the previous specific Fragment from an Activity.??? Can you please comment on that again. I have the same issue too. I want to go back to my previous fragment activity, how to go back, when I start the Intent it goes to the home

Comment: Should you not call `super.onNewIntent(intent)` in override of onNewIntent?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

First take the framelayout in ActivityA,

```
  <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Create method in activityA

```
 public void openFragment(Fragment fragment) {
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment, null).commit();
        String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, backStateName);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(backStateName);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

After this done in your mainactivity and then overide the method like

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
        if (count == 0) {
            if (exit) {
                finish(); // finish activity
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Press Back again to Exit.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                exit = true;
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        exit = false;
                    }
                }, 2 * 1000);

            }
        } else {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
            int c = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
        }
    }
```

Use in this way,

```
Fragment fragment;
   fragment = new FS_PLKit_Calculator();        
   ((FS_Home) getActivity()).openFragment(fragment);
```

try this way you can maintain backstack of your flow.